# Django REST-Auth Password Reset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I am completely confused by the django middleware available:

I simply want to get password-reset (and later password-change) functionality running, using `django` with `rest_auth` on the backend and Vue on the frontend.

## Step 1: Requesting the Reset-Link via Mail

#### Views

So far I have made a `CustomPasswordResetView`:

```py
# project/accounts/views.py
from rest_auth.views import PasswordResetView

class CustomPasswordResetView(PasswordResetView):
pass
```

#### Serializers

and a `CustomPasswordResetSerializer`:

```py
# project/accounts/serializers.py
from rest_auth.serializers import PasswordResetSerializer

class CustomPasswordResetSerializer(PasswordResetSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    password_reset_form_class = ResetPasswordForm

    def validate_email(self, value):
        # Create PasswordResetForm with the serializer
        self.reset_form = self.password_reset_form_class(data=self.initial_data)
        if not self.reset_form.is_valid():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(self.reset_form.errors)

        ###### FILTER YOUR USER MODEL ######
        if not get_user_model().objects.filter(email=value).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_('Invalid e-mail address'))

        return value

    def save(self):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        # Set some values to trigger the send_email method.
        opts = {
            'use_https': request.is_secure(),
            'from_email': getattr(settings, 'DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL'),
            'request': request,
        }
        opts.update(self.get_email_options())
        self.reset_form.save(**opts)
```

#### Settings.py

In the `settings.py` I have these fields, which seem relevant to me for my problem:

```py
# project/vuedj/settings.py
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    "USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER": "accounts.serializers.CustomUserDetailsSerializer",
    "LOGIN_SERIALIZER": "accounts.serializers.CustomUserLoginSerializer",
    "PASSWORD_RESET_SERIALIZER": "accounts.serializers.CustomPasswordResetSerializer"
}
```

(The complete `settings.py` is attached at the bottom)

#### URL patterns

My urls already catch my API request in order to send the Password-Reset Email:

```py
# project/vuedj/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/', include('api.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('', api_views.index, name='home')
]
```

```py
# project/api/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('auth/', include('accounts.urls')),
    # other paths...
]
```

```py
# project/accounts/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', acc_views.UserListView.as_view(), name='user-list'),
    path('login/', acc_views.UserLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', acc_views.UserLogoutView.as_view(),  name='logout'),
    path('register/', acc_views.CustomRegisterView.as_view(),  name='register'),
    path('reset-password/', acc_views.CustomPasswordResetView.as_view(), name='reset-password'),
    path('reset-password-confirm/', acc_views.CustomPasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='reset-password-confirm'),
    path('<int:pk>/', acc_views.UserDetailView.as_view(), name='user-detail')
]
```

#### Email with PW-Reset Token Generator

The CustomPasswordReset view will eventually generate a nice email with a nice pw-reset link. The link is valid, as I click it, I can reset the password through the allauth templates perfectly.

This code is used by rest-auth (indirectly) to generate the reset-token:

```py
# project/.venv/Lib/site-packages/allauth/account/forms.py
def save(self, request, **kwargs):
    current_site = get_current_site(request)
    email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
    token_generator = kwargs.get("token_generator",
                                 default_token_generator)

    for user in self.users:

        temp_key = token_generator.make_token(user)

        # save it to the password reset model
        # password_reset = PasswordReset(user=user, temp_key=temp_key)
        # password_reset.save()

        # send the password reset email
        path = reverse("account_reset_password_from_key",
                       kwargs=dict(uidb36=user_pk_to_url_str(user),
                                   key=temp_key))
        url = build_absolute_uri(
            request, path)

        context = {"current_site": current_site,
                   "user": user,
                   "password_reset_url": url,
                   "request": request}

        if app_settings.AUTHENTICATION_METHOD \
                != AuthenticationMethod.EMAIL:
            context['username'] = user_username(user)
        get_adapter(request).send_mail(
            'account/email/password_reset_key',
            email,
            context)
    return self.cleaned_data["email"]
```

This `PasswordResetTokenGenerator` is used in the code above:

```py
# project/.venv/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/tokens.py
class PasswordResetTokenGenerator:
        """
        Strategy object used to generate and check tokens for the password
        reset mechanism.
        """
        key_salt = "django.contrib.auth.tokens.PasswordResetTokenGenerator"
        secret = settings.SECRET_KEY

        def make_token(self, user):
                """
                Return a token that can be used once to do a password reset
                for the given user.
                """
                return self._make_token_with_timestamp(user, self._num_days(self._today()))

        def check_token(self, user, token):
                """
                Check that a password reset token is correct for a given user.
                """
                if not (user and token):
                        return False
                # Parse the token
                try:
                        ts_b36, hash = token.split("-")
                except ValueError:
                        return False

                try:
                        ts = base36_to_int(ts_b36)
                except ValueError:
                        return False

                # Check that the timestamp/uid has not been tampered with
                if not constant_time_compare(self._make_token_with_timestamp(user, ts), token):
                        return False

                # Check the timestamp is within limit. Timestamps are rounded to
                # midnight (server time) providing a resolution of only 1 day. If a
                # link is generated 5 minutes before midnight and used 6 minutes later,
                # that counts as 1 day. Therefore, PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS = 1 means
                # "at least 1 day, could be up to 2."
                if (self._num_days(self._today()) - ts) > settings.PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS:
                        return False

                return True
```

The classes above will be called by the `rest_auth` `PasswordResetView`:

```py
# project/.venv/Lib/site-packages/rest_auth/views.py
class PasswordResetView(GenericAPIView):
        """
        Calls Django Auth PasswordResetForm save method.

        Accepts the following POST parameters: email
        Returns the success/fail message.
        """
        serializer_class = PasswordResetSerializer
        permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
                # Create a serializer with request.data
                serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
                serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

                serializer.save() # <----- Code from above (TokenGenerator) will be called inside this .save() method
                # Return the success message with OK HTTP status
                return Response(
                        {"detail": _("Password reset e-mail has been sent.")},
                        status=status.HTTP_200_OK
                )
```

As you can see, the Tokengenerator will return a `uidb36` with the token.
It also assumes a `uidb36` when the user would confirm the password-reset.
A generated token (for example the full link in the generated mail) would look like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/accounts/password/reset/key/16-52h-42b222e6dc30690b2e91/
```

Where **`16`** is the user id in base 36 (`uidb36`), I do not yet know what `52h` means, but I assume, the third part of the token is the token itself (`42b222e6dc30690b2e91`)

## Step 2: Send the token to the backend (aka "User clicks link")

I am stuck here.
The [API-Endpoints](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_endpoints.html) of the [Rest-Auth-Framework](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) say:

> /rest-auth/password/reset/confirm/ (POST)
>    `uid`
>    `token`
>    `new_password1`
>    `new_password2`

And when I send an object e.g:

```js
{
    uid: '16', // TODO maybe I have to convert it to base10...
    token: '42b222e6dc30690b2e91',
    new_password1: 'test123A$',
    new_password2: 'test123A$'
}
```

via my api to `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/auth/reset-password/` with the object above in the body of an `axios`-post request, my `CustomPasswordResetConfirmView` is triggered like expected, which is also just a Subclass of `PasswordResetConfirmView` from `rest_auth`, so this code is executed:

```py
# project/.venv/Lib/site-packages/rest_auth/views.py
class PasswordResetConfirmView(GenericAPIView):
        """
        Password reset e-mail link is confirmed, therefore
        this resets the user's password.

        Accepts the following POST parameters: token, uid,
                new_password1, new_password2
        Returns the success/fail message.
        """
        serializer_class = PasswordResetConfirmSerializer
        permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

        @sensitive_post_parameters_m
        def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
                return super(PasswordResetConfirmView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
                serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
                serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
                serializer.save()
                return Response(
                        {"detail": _("Password has been reset with the new password.")}
                )
```

The line `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` will call `run_validation` of the `Serializer(BaseSerializer)` of the `rest_framework`.
This will further use the `PasswordResetConfirmSerializer` of `rest_auth`:

```py
# project/.venv/Lib/site-packages/rest_auth/serializers.py
class PasswordResetConfirmSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        """
        Serializer for requesting a password reset e-mail.
        """
        new_password1 = serializers.CharField(max_length=128)
        new_password2 = serializers.CharField(max_length=128)
        uid = serializers.CharField()
        token = serializers.CharField()

        set_password_form_class = SetPasswordForm

        def custom_validation(self, attrs):
                pass

        def validate(self, attrs):
                self._errors = {}

                # Decode the uidb64 to uid to get User object
                try:
                        uid = force_text(uid_decoder(attrs['uid']))
                        self.user = UserModel._default_manager.get(pk=uid)
                except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, UserModel.DoesNotExist):
                        raise ValidationError({'uid': ['Invalid value']})

                self.custom_validation(attrs)
                # Construct SetPasswordForm instance
                self.set_password_form = self.set_password_form_class(
                        user=self.user, data=attrs
                )
                if not self.set_password_form.is_valid():
                        raise serializers.ValidationError(self.set_password_form.errors)
                if not default_token_generator.check_token(self.user, attrs['token']):
                        raise ValidationError({'token': ['Invalid value']})

                return attrs
```

And as you can finally see, this class is expecting a uidb64 instead of a uidb36 for the user id, and I do not even want to know whether the token-format is anyhow matching what is expected here.

I really cannot find good documentation about how to setup `rest_auth` properly for the full password-reset process: I got the email working, but for me it seems, `rest_auth` would generate a wrong token/reset-link for what it is actually expecting back from the user.

#### Summary

I believe, the password-reset-confirmation process is ending in the correct backend-code, while the email/token-generation is messed up.

All I want is to retrieve a **uid** and a **token** which I can send back to django rest-auth in order to let users reset their passwords.
Currently, it seems that these uids and tokens are created by one library and consumed by another library which both expect and create different formats of tokens and uids?

Thanks in advance!

### Full `settings.py`

Here is my full `settings.py`:

```py
# project/vuedj/settings.py
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
SECRET_KEY = persisted_settings.SECRET_KEY
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost']
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_URLS_REGEX = r'^/api/.*$'
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'corsheaders',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.github',
    'rest_auth',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'sceneries',
    'accounts',
    'api',
    'app',
]

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_FILE_PATH = 'app-messages'
SITE_ID = 1

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username_email'

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USER_EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {"login": "accounts.forms.UserLoginForm"}
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGIN_URL = 'api/v1/accounts/login/'

CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "csrftoken"

REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    "USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER": "accounts.serializers.CustomUserDetailsSerializer",
    "LOGIN_SERIALIZER": "accounts.serializers.CustomUserLoginSerializer",
    "PASSWORD_RESET_SERIALIZER": "accounts.serializers.CustomPasswordResetSerializer"
}

REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
    "REGISTER_SERIALIZER": "accounts.serializers.CustomRegisterSerializer",
}

# Following is added to enable registration with email instead of username
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'vuedj.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            'templates/',
            'templates/emails/'
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'vuedj.wsgi.application'

try:
        DATABASES = persisted_settings.DATABASES
except AttributeError:
        DATABASES = {
                'default': {
                        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
                        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
                }
        }

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ]
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../staticfiles/static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../staticfiles/mediafiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'

NOSE_ARGS = [
    '--with-coverage',
    '--cover-package=app',  # For multiple apps use '--cover-package=foo, bar'
]
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Luckily**, I found a nice library which made my life so easy today:

https://github.com/anx-ckreuzberger/django-rest-passwordreset

`pip install django-rest-passwordreset`

**Got it working like this:**

1. Followed instructions on their website.

My **`accounts/urls.py`** now has the following paths:

```py
# project/accounts/urls.py
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views as acc_views

app_name = 'accounts'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', acc_views.UserListView.as_view(), name='user-list'),
    path('login/', acc_views.UserLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', acc_views.UserLogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('register/', acc_views.CustomRegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
    # NEW: custom verify-token view which is not included in django-rest-passwordreset
    path('reset-password/verify-token/', acc_views.CustomPasswordTokenVerificationView.as_view(), name='password_reset_verify_token'),
    # NEW: The django-rest-passwordreset urls to request a token and confirm pw-reset
    path('reset-password/', include('django_rest_passwordreset.urls', namespace='password_reset')),
    path('<int:pk>/', acc_views.UserDetailView.as_view(), name='user-detail')
]
```

Then I also added a little TokenSerializer for my CustomTokenVerification:

```py
# project/accounts/serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers

class CustomTokenSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    token = serializers.CharField()
```

Then I added a Signal Receiver in the previous derived **`CustomPasswordResetView`**, which now is no longer derived from `rest_auth.views.PasswordResetView` **AND** added a new view **`CustomPasswordTokenVerificationView`**:

```py
# project/accounts/views.py
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django_rest_passwordreset.signals import reset_password_token_created
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from vuedj.constants import site_url, site_full_name, site_shortcut_name
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import parsers, renderers, status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import CustomTokenSerializer
from django_rest_passwordreset.models import ResetPasswordToken
from django_rest_passwordreset.views import get_password_reset_token_expiry_time
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta

class CustomPasswordResetView:
    @receiver(reset_password_token_created)
    def password_reset_token_created(sender, reset_password_token, *args, **kwargs):
        """
          Handles password reset tokens
          When a token is created, an e-mail needs to be sent to the user
        """
        # send an e-mail to the user
        context = {
            'current_user': reset_password_token.user,
            'username': reset_password_token.user.username,
            'email': reset_password_token.user.email,
            'reset_password_url': "{}/password-reset/{}".format(site_url, reset_password_token.key),
            'site_name': site_shortcut_name,
            'site_domain': site_url
        }

        # render email text
        email_html_message = render_to_string('email/user_reset_password.html', context)
        email_plaintext_message = render_to_string('email/user_reset_password.txt', context)

        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
            # title:
            "Password Reset for {}".format(site_full_name),
            # message:
            email_plaintext_message,
            # from:
            "noreply@{}".format(site_url),
            # to:
            [reset_password_token.user.email]
        )
        msg.attach_alternative(email_html_message, "text/html")
        msg.send()


class CustomPasswordTokenVerificationView(APIView):
    """
      An Api View which provides a method to verifiy that a given pw-reset token is valid before actually confirming the
      reset.
    """
    throttle_classes = ()
    permission_classes = ()
    parser_classes = (parsers.FormParser, parsers.MultiPartParser, parsers.JSONParser,)
    renderer_classes = (renderers.JSONRenderer,)
    serializer_class = CustomTokenSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        token = serializer.validated_data['token']

        # get token validation time
        password_reset_token_validation_time = get_password_reset_token_expiry_time()

        # find token
        reset_password_token = ResetPasswordToken.objects.filter(key=token).first()

        if reset_password_token is None:
            return Response({'status': 'invalid'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        # check expiry date
        expiry_date = reset_password_token.created_at + timedelta(hours=password_reset_token_validation_time)

        if timezone.now() > expiry_date:
            # delete expired token
            reset_password_token.delete()
            return Response({'status': 'expired'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        # check if user has password to change
        if not reset_password_token.user.has_usable_password():
            return Response({'status': 'irrelevant'})

        return Response({'status': 'OK'})
```

Now my frontend will provide an option to request the pw-reset link, so the frontend will send a post request to django like this:

```js
// urls.js
const SERVER_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/' // FIXME: change at production (https and correct IP and port)
const API_URL = 'api/v1/'
const API_AUTH = 'auth/'
API_AUTH_PASSWORD_RESET = API_AUTH + 'reset-password/'


// api.js
import axios from 'axios'
import urls from './urls'

axios.defaults.baseURL = urls.SERVER_URL + urls.API_URL
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken'
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'

const api = {
    get,
    post,
    patch,
    put,
    head,
    delete: _delete
}

function post (url, request) {
    return axios.post(url, request)
        .then((response) => Promise.resolve(response))
        .catch((error) => Promise.reject(error))
}


// user.service.js
import api from '@/_api/api'
import urls from '@/_api/urls'

api.post(`${urls.API_AUTH_PASSWORD_RESET}`, email)
    .then( /* handle success */ )
    .catch( /* handle error */ )
```

And the created email will contain a link like this:

```
Click the link below to reset your password.

localhost:8000/password-reset/4873759c229f17a94546a63eb7c3d482e73983495fa40c7ec2a3d9ca1adcf017
```

... which is not defined in the django-urls **by intention!**
Django will let every unknown url pass through and the vue router will decide if the url makes sense or not.
Then I let the frontend send the token to see if it is valid, so the user can already see if the token is already used, expired, or whatever...

```js
// urls.js
const API_AUTH_PASSWORD_RESET_VERIFY_TOKEN = API_AUTH + 'reset-password/verify-token/'

// users.service.js
api.post(`${urls.API_AUTH_PASSWORD_RESET_VERIFY_TOKEN}`, pwResetToken)
    .then( /* handle success */ )
    .catch( /* handle error */ )
```

Now the user will get an error message through Vue, or password-input fields, where they can finally reset the password, which will be sent by the frontend like this:

```js
// urls.js
const API_AUTH_PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM = API_AUTH + 'reset-password/confirm/'

// users.service.js
api.post(`${urls.API_AUTH_PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM}`, {
    token: state[token], // (vuex state)
    password: state[password] // (vuex state)
})
.then( /* handle success */ )
.catch( /* handle error */ )
```

This is the main code. I used custom vue routes to decouple the django rest-endpoints from the frontend visible routes. The rest is done with api requests and handling their responses.

Hope this helps anybody who will have struggles like me in the future.

Comment: You reference sending a post request to `reset-password/confirm/` but it's not specified as a path in your Django urls file, is this intentional?

Comment: @superdee73 I think it is included in the dependency: `include('django_rest_passwordreset.urls', namespace='password_reset')`
EDIT: Yes, confirmed it just now, the url you requested is a sub-url of the `django_rest_passwordreset` library (at least at the time I wrote the answer and in my local repo). You only need to include the parent-url in django with the line above to have all urls from the library implied.

Comment: If you have problems with the post-request, for example if the request is not found by the Django Url parser, double-check the spelling. For example, it is MANDATORY that the url has a slash `/` at the end!

Comment: Would you mind sharing your how your templates look like, where are you placing them and anything else you've done in your settings.oy to not get `django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: user_reset_password.html`? [Just created a question with it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61322120/5675325), in case you'd like to answer.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 I comment here so others can see it as well: https://gitlab.com/electrocnic/odpr/-/tree/master/backend ... I did not use email sending because Windows would not let me, but the templates are located in `static_templates/email` and the views in `accounts/views`. Maybe it helps?

Comment: can you add also your vuedj constants file.

Comment: @ytsejam For example see an earlier commit, I removed this file later on because my https://gitlab.com/electrocnic/vue-django-ci-cd-boilerplate project solves the develop-vs.-debug-vs.-release problem in a different way (by injecting gitlab-ci variables). But here you can see how it may or may not look if you need it in this static form: https://gitlab.com/electrocnic/odpr/-/blob/0.0.6/backend/vuedj/constants.py

Comment: Direct implementation here : https://studygyaan.com/django/django-rest-framework-tutorial-change-password-and-reset-password#:~:text=Change%20Password%20API%20using%20Django,the%20verification%20of%20old%20password.&text=That's%20it.,and%20the%20following%20in%20content.

Comment: After clicking the password reset link in the email, why/how does vue automatically trigger the verify-token post in users.service.js?

Comment: @alkadelik The url in the mail (e.g. `/password-reset/4873759c229f17a94546a63eb7c3d482e73983495fa40c7ec2a3d9ca1adcf017`) is catched/defined by the vue-router, not by the django url settings. Therefore, vue will do whatever you define in your vue-router settings. I would pass the token to a modal component or something like this. Also, I called a `user-service` function where the `api.post(${urls.API_AUTH_PASSWORD_RESET_VERIFY_TOKEN}...` is placed and I did this either from the router settings directly or from the modal component in let's say the `mounted()` function or `beforeRouteUpdate`

Comment: See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode

and https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes

Comment: Great, it's been working..but didn't understand whats happening underhood

Comment: Sending email for resetting password seems too slow, might be for the signal.Won't be a performance issue?

Answer (score 0):

We have the same setup and I can tell you that it works but I can't help you with the base 36 except that even the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView) says that it is base 64!

However, you've written that this theoretical part is not so important for you and let's find the point you are missing. The setup is a bit confusing because you don't need everything of allauth. I don't understand exactly where you are stuck. Therefore, I want to tell you how I did it:

I defined the password reset URL just for Django/allauth to find it when creating the link in the email:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

PASSWORD_RESET = (
    r'^auth/password-reset-confirmation/'
    r'(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/'
    r'(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})$'
)

urlpatterns += [
    re_path(
        PASSWORD_RESET,
        TemplateView.as_view(),
        name='password_reset_confirm',
    ),
]
```

You don't have to do that (because you `include('allauth.urls')`, you actually [don't need these URLs](https://gist.github.com/dgilge/dbe9260208aadee535cef7c412a1162e#5-urls)) but I want to make clear that this URL does not point to the backend! That said, let your frontend serve this URL with a form to enter a new password and then use axios or something to `POST` `uid`, `token`, `new_password1` and `new_password2` to your endpoint.

In your case the endpoint is

```
path(
    'reset-password-confirm/',
    acc_views.CustomPasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
    name='reset-password-confirm'
),
```

Does this help you? Otherwise, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your help but all what you said was something I already understood :/
Lucky me I found an alternative solution which I got running now :)

Comment: @ElectRocnic please let us know about your solution <3

Comment: @ImanSadrian see my answer which I already checked as correct.