# how to change the Django password reset email style and content

Tags: django

So I'm using the built-in Django password reset system. It works fine, but I'm not satisfied with the email sent to the users. I want to change all of it, from styles to texts. But how am I supposed to do that? I have read some solutions here, but they are more confusing than being helpful.

Comment: [This might be of help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61322120/5675325).

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the existing email here: `<projectName>/lib/python/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html`

Or you can create an new folder called `registration` and add the templates to it to create your own:

```
password_reset_form.html
password_reset_subject.txt
password_reset_email.html
password_reset_done.html
password_reset_confirm.html
password_reset_complete.html
```

and then include all auth views to your projets url's:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

Comment: How do I access the lib folder? There is no lib folder in my project?

Comment: That's it? Do I need to create some views or URLs?

Comment: yes sorry, forgot about the URL's. here you can find a tutorial: https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-password-reset-tutorial